# Cramp and heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, websocket, cramp

I have been playing around with Cramp to do some real time pushing of information in an app. Its all working great locally but when I push off to heroku I seem to be having issues with the ports.

I have a socket set up in cramp which inherits from websocket

```
class LiveSocket < Cramp::Websocket
```

and I also have a cramp action called home which basically just renders some erb for the home page

```
class HomeAction < Cramp::Action
```

in my route file I set up the following and also a static file server

```
Rack::Builder.new do

  puts "public file at #{File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), '../public')}"
  file_server = Rack::File.new(File.join(File.dirname(__FILE__), 'public'))



 routes = HttpRouter.new do
   add('/').to(HomeAction)
   get('/LiveSocket').to(LiveSocket)
 end
  run Rack::Cascade.new([file_server, routes])



end
```

Then on the client end the javascript connects to

```
var ws = new WebSocket("ws://<%= request.host_with_port %>/LiveSocket");
```

As I say locally it all works. We connect and start receiving notifications from the server. On heroku we run thin on the Cedar stack and have a profile which looks like

```
web: bundle exec thin  --timeout 0 start -p $PORT
```

When I load up the site the page itself loads fine but on trying to connect the websocket I get an error which says

```
servername.herokuapp.com Unexpected response code: 200
```

I am guessing this has something to do with how heroku routes its requests but I do know that you can run a node.js websocket server on heroku so figure there must be a way to get this working too.

Thanks in advance for any help.

cheers

stuart

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Heroku supports websockets :( http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/http-routing#the_herokuappcom_http_stack

Comment: Ah well that would explain it. I must have stared at that page 100 times and never noticed that. I guess if I set up socketIO in the client side I can fall back to long polling.